# Json - get count of elements

Tags: json

Emacs 26.1
Here json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "my name"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "my name3"
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "name": "my name3"
  }
]
```

As you can see the count of elements are **3**.
Nice.
Is it possible to get count of elements?
Suppose I has large json and I need to get count of elements?
Maybe has some method that can do this.

P.S.
Structure of one item is:

```
{
    "id": xx,
    "name": "xxxx"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json-read` function

> `json-read` is a compiled Lisp function in `json.el`.
>
> Parse and return the JSON object following point.
>   Advances point just past JSON object.

like this

```el
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (length (json-read)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my custom function:

```
(defun json-count-elements ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (message "Count of json elements: %d" (length (json-read)))))
```